# Trying to understand hashCode() implementation of the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashcode

Looking through the java source code, I faced with incomprehensible for me construction in the hashCode() method of the class AbstractList. This is implementation of the hashCode method for ArrayList. I don't understand how it iterates with for-each.

```
 public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 1;
    for (E e : this)  //<--???
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
    return hashCode;
}
```

**E** is the type of the element. But to which class(type) pointer **this** belongs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But to which class(type) pointer this belongs?

`this` is the list that `hashCode` was called on. So the compile-time type is `AbstractList<E>`.

It's saying "for every element in this list, include that element's hash code in the result".

Comment: This is so easy. Shame on me.

Answer (score 1):

The `E e` refers to the **generic type** in that `ArrayList<E>` (see the `E`?)

Think of it as

```
ArrayList<String> list 
for(String e : list) {
```

Only because you're **inside the list** your `list` becomes `this`

Answer (score 1):

`List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();`

`this` - It will refer `personList`
`e` - It will refer object  of `Person` class